# Javascript, how do I make the up key only pressed once

Tags: javascript

```
onEvent("screenGamemode3", "keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key == "Left"|| event.key == "a") {
    xloc = xloc - 10;
  } else if (event.key == "Right" || event.key == "d" ) {
    xloc = xloc + 10;
  } else if (event.key == "Down" || event.key == "s" ) {
    yloc = yloc + 20;
  } else if (event.key == "Up" || event.key == "w") {
    yloc = yloc - 50;
  }
});
```

I want the  `else if (event.key == "Up" || event.key == "w") { yloc = yloc - 50;`part only clickable once and not be able to get clicked twice

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: What library are you using? `onEvent` is not a standard javascript.

Comment: I have tried many things off google for example eventlisteners and nothing of it worked. Also im coding on code.org so idk im pretty new dude

Answer (score 1):

You could keep track of the last pressed key, but I'm guessing you probably want to use `keyup` instead of `keydown`. The latter is fired continuously while `keyup` is only fired once. Or at least until the user presses the same key again.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use a `flag variable`, by default set it to `false` and when `KEYUP` is clicked - set it to `true`. And check also your `flag variable` in your `else if` condition. Here is the code:

```js
let isKeyupPressed = false;

window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {

  if (event.key == "ArrowLeft"|| event.key == "a") {
    // xloc -= 10;
  } else if (event.key == "ArrowRight" || event.key == "d" ) {
    // xloc += 10;
  } else if (event.key == "ArrowDown" || event.key == "s" ) {
    // yloc += 20;
  } else if (!isKeyupPressed && (event.key == "ArrowUp" || event.key == "w")) {
    // yloc -= 50;
    isKeyupPressed = true;
    console.log('Arrow Up invoke? ', event.key); // it will log only once
  }
  
  console.log(event.key);
})
```

Comment: Thank you bro, but I tried this already and it gives me thise "ERROR: Line: 648: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (648:6)"

Comment: @Darekia that means you have problem(s) in your code syntax, not in your logic. Whatever let me try in codepen

Comment: @Darekia now see my answer, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, but can something like this resolve your problem ?

```
let isFirst = true;
onEvent("screenGamemode3", "keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key == "Left"|| event.key == "a") {
    xloc = xloc - 10;
  } else if (event.key == "Right" || event.key == "d" ) {
    xloc = xloc + 10;
  } else if (event.key == "Down" || event.key == "s" ) {
    yloc = yloc + 20;
  }
    else if ((event.key == "Up" || event.key == "w") && isFirst == true) {
    yloc = yloc - 50;

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining a count flag & using it in the if(), can do the job.
refer following code.

```js
let keyPressCount  = 0;
if(){
    //your code
}
else if ((event.key == "Up" || event.key == "w") && keyPressCount === 0) {
    yloc = yloc - 50;  
    keyPressCount = 1
}
```